# JS Promise waitFor refresh Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

The situation is simple :

I have a nodejs server (called it API-A) that use Bluebird as a Promise handler. 
I have a client(browser) that ask data through the API-A which get the data from another API (API-B). API-B could be a Weather service from example and then API-A aggregate the data with other data and send it back to client.

The situation is the next: API-B need a token with a TTL of 1800 second. 
So for each request done by the client, I check if my token is expired or not.

I have this kind of code :

```
function getActivities()
{
return this.requestAuthorisation()
       .then(()=>{
        // some other code that is not interesting
       })
}
```

Everything works fine with the glory of promise. 
requestAuthorisation() check if the token is valid (next!!!) and if not (I do a request the API-B to refresh the token)
The problem is here: 
between the time, the token is expired and the time to obtain a fresh one, some times happen. if 1000 clients ask at the same time these, I will have 1000 request of token to API-B, that is not cool.

How can I avoid that ? I try to avoid a cron-way to do it, to avoid unnecessary call and the problem is the same.

I try to create a sort of global variable (boolean) that track the refreshing status of the token but impossible to find a sort of Promise.WaitFor (variable change) 
the Promise.all can not be use because I am in different scope of event.

Is there a way to queue until the token is refresh ?

Please help !

Comment: Can you access the Promise itself from the scope you're waiting for it? There might be multiple ways, either create a separate promise to wait for, return the promise from the first promise and execute after the second one, ... - at the moment I am not quite sure about you're architecture from the code side - maybe; could you be more specific in that sense?

Comment: No I can get directly the promise. The process is event-based (the request of the client on the API) so it's difficult to cross the flow of the 1000 clients but You give me an idea... thanks

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Comment: not know, not in the current UserStory but I will give the answer as fast as I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this write, we need to do two things:

- Do not call our refreshToken several times when one is in progress
- Once completed, let all the waiting request know that request for the token in completed so that they can continue their work.

If you combine Observable pattern and a state to maintain the in-progress state, this can be done like below

```
// MyObservable.js:
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

let inProgress = false;

function MyObservable() {
  EventEmitter.call(this);
}
// This is the function responsible for getting a refresh token
MyObservable.prototype.getToken = function(token) {
  console.log('Inside getToken');
  if (!inProgress) {
    console.log('calling fetchToken');
    resultPromise = this.fetchToken();
    inProgress = true;
    resultPromise.then((result) => {
      console.log('Resolved fetch token');
      inProgress = false;
      this.emit('done', 'token refreshed');
    });
  }

}
// This is a mock function to simulate the promise based API.
MyObservable.prototype.fetchToken = function(token) {
  console.log('Inside fetchToken');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('resolving');
      resolve("Completed");
    }, 2000);
  });
}

util.inherits(MyObservable, EventEmitter);
module.exports = MyObservable;
```

Now we can implement this and observe for the call to complete

```
const MyObservable = require('./MyObservable');

const observable = new MyObservable();


const A = () => {
  console.log('Inside A');
  observable.on('done', (message) => {
    console.log('Completed A');
  });
  observable.getToken('test');
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(A, 1000);
}
```

If we run this code, you will get an output where `fetchToeken` is called only once even though our method `A` is called 5 times during the same duration.

Hope this helps!